# ng-Repeat not working at certain depth, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this situation where my ng-Repeat I can get working to a certain level but any deeper I can't find the array.

Here is my code and also a plunkr below:

```
 <div ng-repeat="row in data">
    <label  ng-repeat="key in keys">
      {{row[key]}}
      <input name="optradio" type="radio"/>
    </label>
```

This PLunker works ok but I want to go down to the Options layer to display just Option1 and Option2.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xNVVFohA6DeU9nCgi7fQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options` is an array thus you just have to iterate over it

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.data = [{
      "property": "http://api.mydomain.co.uk/",
      "type": "Selection",
      "options": [{
        "text": "Option 01",
        "value": "http://api.mydomain.co.uk/O",
        "type": "SelectionOption"
      }, {
        "text": "Option 02",
        "value": "http://api.mydomain.co.uk/L",
        "type": "SelectionOption"
      }]
    }];

    $scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.data[0]);
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">

  <div ng-repeat="row in data">
    <label ng-repeat="opt in row.options">
      {{opt.text}}
      <input name="optradio" type="radio" />
    </label>
    <br>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @wwwredback No problem mate ! Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it helped you